# SQL 2014 secondary node installation fail with "Failed to retrieve data for this request" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need some assistance with resolving the above. I'm trying to install a secondary on a SQL node on a Failover Cluster, but keep on getting the same error: "***Failed to retrieve data for this request***"

I've tried all the solutions I found on the web:

•   Check and confirm correct permissions for the correct user

•   Remote Registry service enabled

•   VM part of the FCI.

•   HKey_Local_Machine registry entry and permissions correct

Still, I'm getting the same error.

Enclosed is the summary and detail log files.

Summary Log:

```
  Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2146233088
  Exit facility code:            19
  Exit error code:               5376
  Exit message:                  Failed to retrieve data for this request.
  Start time:                    2020-03-30 10:38:08
  End time:                      2020-03-30 10:38:37
  Requested action:              AddNode
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8&EvtType=0xE8A0C283%400xAC7B1A58%401233%4053&EvtType=0xE8A0C283%400xAC7B1A58%401233%4053

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  NLDSQLMVQ12
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  Yes

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQL\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        AddNode
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CONFIRMIPDEPENDENCYCHANGE:     false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:          
  FAILOVERCLUSTERIPADDRESSES:    <empty>
  FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:    <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200330_103807\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               The rule result report file is not available.

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException
    Message: 
        Failed to retrieve data for this request.
    HResult : 0x80131500
    Data: 
      HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
      HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
      HelpLink.LinkId = 20476
      HelpLink.EvtType = 0xE8A0C283@0xAC7B1A58@1233@53
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.ProcessDTbl(DataTable dt, Int32 level)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectSqlDiscoveryData(String machineName)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectDiscoveryData(String machineName)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.LoadData(IEnumerable`1 machineNames, String discoveryDocRootPath, String clusterDiscoveryDocRootPath)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.RunDiscoveryAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
    Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException
        Message: 
                The network path was not found.

        HResult : 0x84d10035
                FacilityCode : 1233 (4d1)
                ErrorCode : 53 (0035)
        Data: 
          WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException@Win32Error
        Stack: 
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.CreateBaseKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, IntPtr hKey, String keyName, RegistryAccess access, RegistryView view)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.GetLocalMachine(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryAccess access, RegistryView view)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineRootKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView registryView)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineSubKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView regView, String regPath, RegistryAccess registryAccess)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.GetSql2kMsiInstanceListInHive(String machineName, RegistryView regView)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.LoadSql2kInstanceList(String machineName)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.Product.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
```

Detai Log:

```
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineRootKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView registryView)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineSubKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView regView, String regPath, RegistryAccess registryAccess)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.GetSql2kMsiInstanceListInHive(String machineName, RegistryView regView)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.LoadSql2kInstanceList(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.Product.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.ProcessDTbl(DataTable dt, Int32 level)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectSqlDiscoveryData(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectDiscoveryData(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.LoadData(IEnumerable`1 machineNames, String discoveryDocRootPath, String clusterDiscoveryDocRootPath)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.RunDiscoveryAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction" threw an exception during execution.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: Failed to retrieve data for this request. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException: Failed to retrieve data for this request. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException: The network path was not found.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.CreateBaseKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, IntPtr hKey, String keyName, RegistryAccess access, RegistryView view)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.GetLocalMachine(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryAccess access, RegistryView view)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineRootKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView registryView)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineSubKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView regView, String regPath, RegistryAccess registryAccess)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.GetSql2kMsiInstanceListInHive(String machineName, RegistryView regView)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.LoadSql2kInstanceList(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.Product.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.ProcessDTbl(DataTable dt, Int32 level)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectSqlDiscoveryData(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectDiscoveryData(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.LoadData(IEnumerable`1 machineNames, String discoveryDocRootPath, String clusterDiscoveryDocRootPath)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.RunDiscoveryAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionEngine.RunActionQueue()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.Workflow.RunWorkflow(WorkflowObject workflowObject, HandleInternalException exceptionHandler)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ExecuteWorkflowAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper(WorkflowObject metaDb, ActionKey action, ActionMetadata actionMetadata, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.InvokeAction(WorkflowObject metabase, TextWriter statusStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.PendingActions.InvokeActions(WorkflowObject metaDb, TextWriter loggingStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: Received request to add the following file to Watson reporting: C:\Users\vann_k_sa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC166.tmp
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:     Message: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         Failed to retrieve data for this request.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:     HResult : 0x80131500
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:     Data: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:       HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:       HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:       HelpLink.LinkId = 20476
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:     Stack: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.ProcessDTbl(DataTable dt, Int32 level)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectSqlDiscoveryData(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.CollectDiscoveryData(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.SqlDiscoveryDatastoreInterface.LoadData(IEnumerable`1 machineNames, String discoveryDocRootPath, String clusterDiscoveryDocRootPath)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.RunDiscoveryAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:     Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         Message: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 The network path was not found.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         HResult : 0x84d10035
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 FacilityCode : 1233 (4d1)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 ErrorCode : 53 (0035)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         Data: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:           WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException@Win32Error
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:         Stack: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.CreateBaseKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, IntPtr hKey, String keyName, RegistryAccess access, RegistryView view)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.GetLocalMachine(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryAccess access, RegistryView view)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineRootKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView registryView)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.GetLocalMachineSubKey(ServiceContainer ctx, String machineName, RegistryView regView, String regPath, RegistryAccess registryAccess)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.GetSql2kMsiInstanceListInHive(String machineName, RegistryView regView)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.DiscoveryEnumObject.LoadSql2kInstanceList(String machineName)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Discovery.Product.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:13 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Watson Bucket 2 
 Original Parameter Values 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 0 : SQL Server 2014@RTM@ 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 1 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 2 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistry.CreateBaseKey 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 3 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException@-2146233088 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 4 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException@1233@53 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 5 : RunRemoteDiscoveryAction 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 8 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlRegistryException@Win32Error 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: 
 Final Parameter Values 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 0 : SQL Server 2014@RTM@ 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 1 : 0x6785B09D 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 2 : 0xE8A0C283 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 3 : 0x74E34741 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 4 : 0xAC7B1A58@1233@53 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 5 : RunRemoteDiscoveryAction 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:19 Slp: Parameter 8 : 0xD195CE25 

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Microsoft SQL Server to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200330_103807\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Microsoft SQL Server.reg_
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Uninstall to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200330_103807\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: Unable to open hklm registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer, error The system cannot find the file specified.

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: Unable to open hklm registry key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server, error The system cannot find the file specified.

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key Uninstall to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200330_103807\Registry_SOFTWARE_Wow6432Node_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: Unable to open hklm registry key SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer, error The system cannot find the file specified.

(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Failed to retrieve data for this request.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Watson bucket for exception based failure has been created
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: WER: Application level consent value 'False' was mapped to consent status 'WerConsentDenied'
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: WER: Result of the submission:: 'WerDisabled'
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: WER: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data repository
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Sco: File 'C:\Windows\system32\Cluster.exe' does not exist
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Collecting Cluster Logs using PowerShell:
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:20 Slp: Running: Powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command Get-ClusterLog -Destination 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200330_103807' -Node 'NLDSQLMVQ12' -TimeSpan 1
(09) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: 
(09) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
(09) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: ----                -------------     ------ ----                              
(09) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: -a---        2020-03-30  10:38 AM       8526 NLDSQLMVQ12_cluster.log           
(09) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: 
(09) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: Process returned 0
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: Cluster log generation completed successfully
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:24 Slp: Dumping final cluster state.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: Completed dumping final cluster state.
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: 
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: Error result: -2146233088
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: Result facility code: 19
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: Result error code: 5376
(01) 2020-03-30 10:38:37 Slp: SQM Service: Sqm does not have active session.
```

Many thanks.

Koosvn

Comment: This belongs to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where is your install file located? I've experienced install issues like this before. By copying the install file to a folder where `system` has full access to, usually resolved the problem. Maybe try this?

Comment: It is on the local c: drive with full access.